# Error in Xcode for Swift 5 "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, dyld, swift5

I just made the update for Swift 5 on my macbook and for now I can't run any code with Xcode, it gives me the following output during runtime (the building is ok).

I already tried to:

- Clean the solution. and build again
- Make the RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks".
- Make the ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES.
- Make the EMBED_ASSET_PACKS_IN_PRODUCT_BUNDLE = YES

Here the code I try to run:

```swift
import Foundation

print("Hello World")
```

Output:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/***/Documents/MyProject/Build/Products/Debug/MyProject
Reason: image not found
```

Expected output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: check my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367359/getting-an-issue-with-upgrade-to-xcode-10-2/55374924#55374924

Comment: I also tried it it seems to be something else

Answer (score 10):

I'm sorry, I just found the solution to the problem.

If that occurs to someone you only have to download [the swift 5 runtime support](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1998?locale=fr_FR).
It seems to be that the runtime virtual machine for swift5 is not the same than for swift4

[the swift 5 runtime support](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1998?locale=fr_FR).cannot install to Mac OS 10.14.4,how to solve it?